# How can I change my connectionstring in App.config and my database (sqlite) when I setup my project?

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite

I using Entity framework and sqlite to my project.

when I setup my project I don't know to change my connectionstring :

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="mainEntities"
        connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model
    1.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite.EF6;
        provider connection string=&quot;
            data source=C:\Users\Nam\Desktop\ConsoleApp\ProductDB.db&quot;" 
    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
        </connectionStrings>
```

so I decided to let it stay here (not change)
and after setup I can't open my app. My database ( .db) stay from another file 
( not in my project ).

I saw many videos on youtube but It mostly using ADO.NET .

Plaese help me code to change connectionstring and all above is the way can create file .db in my project.

thanks guy .

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a SQLite Data provider, then you will be able to add a SQLite database datasource trough the VS wizard (it will create the connection string).

Follow this steps for details:
https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/EF6-workflow-with-SQLite-DDEX-provider